# jspx script element on GlassFish v3

Tags: javascript, jsp, glassfish, java-ee-5, jspx

The .war is served from GlassFish v3. I am trying to include a javascript file from my jspx.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/base/interface/Service.js"></script>
```

I get the following in my http response

```
<script src="/base/interface/Service.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

The problem is that it should include the `</script>` tag. I believe this is why it works on Chrome, but not on Firefox or IE. Any idea how to force `<script></script>`

Update: Not sure if any of this is pertinent, but here is the beginning of my jspx file

```
<jsp:root version="2.0"
      xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
      xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
            doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
            doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"/>
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/> 
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `<script ...><jsp:text> </jsp:text></script>` and that retained the closing tag. I think this is ugly, so if anyone has a better answer I would definitely be interested.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the solution that IBM officially endorses if you're stuck using Websphere Application Server

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, jspx is known to "minimize" empty elements. One way to prevent the minimization without adding a space to the rendered HTML is to insert a comment. For example:

```
<script ...><!-- keep open/close tags --></script>
```

It is still ugly, though.

Comment: Work for Tomcat (6) but not for Websphere (7).

Answer (score 0):

A potentially cleaner solution would be to create a custom taglib that outputs correct HTML, e.g.:

```
<m:htmlScript type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"/>
```

producing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js">
```

Another alternative would be to encapsulate the tag in CDATA:

```
<![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>]]>
```

I covered this topic in more detail here:
[How to produce valid HTML with JSPX? (not XHTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639643/how-to-produce-valid-html-with-jspx-not-xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another ugly solution:

```
<tag>${null}</tag>
```