# Keep JSPX from creating self closing tags (<div></div> != <div/>)

Tags: java, xml, groovy, jspx

JSPX has the lovely side effect of turning:

```
<div class="magic"></div>
```

Into:

```
<div class="magic" />
```

For many browsers this causes pandemonium and mayhem with layout even though it is valid XHTML. 
Consequently I have resorted to using a groovy script to find all possible bad HTML with the following regex:

```
def m = html =~ /<(\w+)[^>]*?><\/(\w+)>/
def bad = m.findAll { it[1] == it[2]  };
```

**Is there way to have the JSPX XML processor not to self close tags?**

Comment: `For many browsers this causes pandemonium and mayhem with layout even though it is valid XHTML.`, do you mean IE? XHTML is valid on Firefox 3 and higher, Safari 4 and higher, Google Chrome and Opera. I don't think IE8 passed XHTML standard.

Comment: @Gentleman It causes pandemonium in Firefox too, I'm afraid.

Comment: Weird, How come Firefox is suffering?

Comment: I believe the two browsers that it affects *most* are Firefox and Opera. However I did see some weird behavior for <a/> tags for all browsers. With JQuery and friends its very common to have empty tags these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no elegant solution to this (read: configurable on container level). Check "[jspx script element on GlassFish v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058649/jspx-script-element-on-glassfish-v3)" for possible workarounds.

Answer (score 9):

I've been using `<div><jsp:text/></div>`

Comment: Thanks a ton Glenn Lane. jsp:text/>
worked like a charm. i created a beautiful layout using dreamweaver and when I ran the first time on server, jspx messed up by adding self-close tags and also removing other valid tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can try specifying content inside the element that won't affect how the HTML renders, but will prevent the XHTML from being serialized as a self-closing element; like a **comment, processing instruction, or non-breaking white space character**(`&#x200B;`).

Comment: Yeah I have been using <!-- -->. So <div><!-- --></div> seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Neeme there seems to be no solution to this problem.
However I have written a Groovy script that you can have Maven call (GMaven) to check for possible XHTML tags that will get self closed.

This script probably needs better error messages and does not handle all cases but has so far mitigated the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy


def srcdir = project.properties['srcdir'];
def badFiles = [];

def checkFile(badFiles, file) {
    def htmlLines = file.readLines();
    def found = [];
    int i = 0;
    for (html in htmlLines) {
        ++i;
        //print html;
        def m = html =~ /<(\w+)[^>]*?><\/(\w+)>/
        def bad = m.findAll { it[1] == it[2]  };
        if (bad)
            found.add(['bad' : bad, 'line' : i]);
    }
    if (found) {
        badFiles << file;
        println "File had bad HTML: " + file.canonicalPath;
        println found;
    }

}

def ant = new AntBuilder();
scanner = ant.fileScanner {
    fileset(dir:srcdir) {
        include(name:"**/*.jspx")
    }
}

for (f in scanner) {
    //println "Checking file: " + f.canonicalPath;
    checkFile(badFiles, f);
}
if (badFiles) { 
    println "Bad files: " + badFiles;
    fail('Bad files: ' + badFiles);
}
```