# Twitter Bootstrap Navbar draws incorrectly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've copy+pasted the navbar code from [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) into my jspx file.

The result looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3aX2B/).

Copy+pasting the code directly into jsfiddle results in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3aX2B/1).

Looking at the code, I don't see any difference that should matter:

- In one version, we have `<b />` tags, and in the other, we have `<b></b>` tags
- some of the whitespace is different
- some of the attribute orders are different.

For reference, the complete HTML follows:

Working version:

```
<div version="2.0">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
                data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar" /><span
                    class="icon-bar" /><span class="icon-bar" />
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
            class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown"
                    class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider" />
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider" />
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
            </ul>
            <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input placeholder="Search" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown"
                    class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret" /></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider" />
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Broken version:

```
<div version="2.0">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
                data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar" /><span
                    class="icon-bar" /><span class="icon-bar" />
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
            class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown"
                    class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret" /></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider" />
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider" />
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
            </ul>
            <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input placeholder="Search" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown"
                    class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret" /></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider" />
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the self-closing tags are the problem.

The answer to this question: [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5) says so.

I'm going to go with the answer to [Keep JSPX from creating self closing tags (<div></div> != <div/>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907744/keep-jspx-from-creating-self-closing-tags-div-div-div) as a workaround.