# How to insert a Java string into an HTML table

Tags: java, javascript, html, css

I am using `java` within a `.jsp` file and need to output account information in an `HTML` table. My code goes like this:

```
    <%    
    UserAccount ADuser = au.getAccountByEmail(user.getUserName());

    String fname = ADuser.getFirstName();
    %>
```

My question is how do I insert `fname` into a `<td>` such as this:

`<td width="82%" height="30">'first name here</td>'`

Thanks for the help

Comment: How use `<%=ADuser.getFirstName()%>` in td ?

Comment: Put this as an answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use scriptlet `<%= %>` in table data,

```
<%=ADuser.getFirstName()%>
```

Or can use jsp expression `${}` like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165715/jsp-tags-scriptlet-how-to-enable-scriptlet)

```
<% request.setAttribute("firstName", ADuser.getFirstName()); %>

//then in table data
<td..>${firstName}</td>
```

Comment: Don't use scriptlets, we are living in the 21st century, not the 11th century.  Use EL Expressions.

Comment: @DwB Sure this is just to be simple and i updated with El usage.